# MongoDB, nodejs: killed. Утечка памяти

Tags: node.js, mongodb, утечка-памяти

Необходимо записать в базу около 50 000 записей. Не хочет доходить до конца - обрывается. Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать скрипт. Что здесь может быть не так? Добавилось 20 000 записей и выдало "killed".

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const moment = require("moment");
const axios = require("axios");
const alog = require("axios-logger");
const { Orders } = require("./db");
const { Types } = mongoose;

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "URL",
  timeout: 45000,
});
instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.params = config.params || {};
  config.params["userlogin"] = "LOGIN";
  config.params["userpsw"] = "PASS";
  return alog.requestLogger(config);
});

(async () => {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/abcp", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
  });
  var period = 2;
  var start = moment().subtract(1, "y"),
    next = start;

  for (; !next.isAfter(moment()); ) {
    next = start.clone().add(period, "weeks");
    var r = await instance.get("cp/orders", {
      params: {
        dateCreatedStart: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"),
        dateCreatedEnd: next.format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00"),
      },
    });
    console.log(`Status: ${r.status}`);

    var data = [];
    var counter = 0;
    r.data.map(async (i) => {
      data.push({
         updateOne: {
            filter: {number: i.number},
            update: i,
            upsert: true
         }
      })
      counter++;
      if (counter % 1000 == 0) { 
         try {
            await Orders.bulkWrite(data, {ordered: false, j: false, wtimeout: 30000});
            console.log("added");
            data = [];
         } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
         }
      }
    }); 
    start = next;
  }
})();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
arr.splice(0, arr.length)
```

Для удаления элементов массива

Comment: Память все равно увеличивается :(

Comment: Работает только память может и не освободить. Нужно будет дождаться GC чтоб освободить память.

Comment: Вы попробуйте. Что вы теряете?

Comment: Я попробовал: https://prnt.sc/ttsa61

Comment: И измените все глобальные переменные var на let либо const

Comment: Неа, память все равно растет(

Comment: Мда прям как у Ани Кузнецовой ..опа растет

Comment: высвобождайте r после того как не надо

Comment: а будет ли работать delete r?

Comment: Если результат вычисления выражения не является свойством (объекта), delete ничего не делает.

Comment: delete эффективен только применительно к свойствам объектов. Он не оказывает никакого влияния на имена переменных и функций.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: А каким способом тогда удалять ее? r = null?

Comment: Для начала очистите его данные по остальному думаю не такая беда

Comment: r.data.splice и потом delete r.data

Comment: Хм, все равно растет))

https://prnt.sc/ttt586

Comment: Сдвиги изменения хоть есть? или про100 гадаем. Вы понимаете я ведь не вижу всего и про100 так смотреть на ваш частичный исходник и давать советы не про100

Comment: Сдвигов нет вообще почему-то. 
Вот полный код: https://codeshare.io/21jmk1

Comment: Я подумаю, посмотрим может кто ещё подкинет идеи